# Counting lattice paths from $(0,0,0)$ to $(n,n,n)$ for which $y+1\ge x\ge y\ge z$.

Tags: combinatorics

Let $$Ω = \{(x, y, z) ∈ \mathbb Z^3
:  y + 1 ≥ x ≥ y ≥ z ≥ 0\}.$$ A frog moves along the points
of $Ω$ by jumps of length $1$. For every positive integer $n$, determine the number of paths the frog
can take to reach $(n, n, n)$ starting from $(0, 0, 0)$ in exactly $3n$ jumps.

In my opinion, in the coordinate Oxyz we get (x,y,z) to determine the position of the toad, because the jump must always be at most 3n, so the toad must always go forward.  for 1 unit, and we always get that x+y+z=3n, we'll always know where the coordinates are when we define n, what confuses me is how paths work here  For this problem, I have tried many different paths definition but everything is not so good.  Thanks for all the comments

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2):

Let's say that $X$ represents a step in the $x$-direction, and $Y$ and $Z$ represent steps in the $y$ and $z$ directions. A typical path for $n=2$ would be $XYXZYZ$. A path a string of $3n$ symbols, consisting of $n$ each of $X,Y$ and $Z$, subject to the inequalities $y_t+1\ge x_t\ge y_t\ge z_t$ for all $t\in \{1,\dots,3n\}$, where $x_t$ is the number of $X$'s in the first $t$ symbols of the string, and similarly for $y_t$ and $z_t$.

The first simplifying observation is that the path must start with an $X$, and thereafter, the occurrences of $X$ and $Y$ must alternate between $X$ and $Y$. This is because the $y+1\ge x\ge y$ conditions. So, we can instead replace both $X$ and $Y$ with a single symbol, call it $W$, and choose a sequence of $3n$ symbols consisting of $2n$ copies of $W$ and $n$ copies of $Z$; there is then a unique way to replace the $W$'s with alternating $X$'s and $Y$'s to produce a valid sequence.

We no longer have to worry about the $y+1\ge x\ge y$ inequalities. Instead, we have
$$
w\ge 2z,
$$
which follows because if there $w$ instances of $W$, then that translates to $\lfloor w/2\rfloor$ instances of $Y$, and we need $y\ge z$. But this is exactly the ties-allowed variant of Bertrand's ballot problem. As proved in *Four Proofs of the Ballot Theorem*, the number of sequences consisting of $2n$ copies of $W$ and $n$ copies of $Z$, such that any initial segment has at least twice as many $W$'s as $Z$'s, is
$$
\frac{1}{2n+1}\binom{3n}n
$$

> Renault, Marc. “Four Proofs of the Ballot Theorem.” Mathematics Magazine, vol. 80, no. 5, 2007, pp. 345–52. JSTOR, http://www.jstor.org/stable/27643060.